# C++ atomic: ошибка LLVM из NDK

Tags: c++, android-ndk, llvm

При включении любых C++ заголовков появляется ошибка в заголовках LLVM:

```
In file included from ./test.cpp:4:
In file included from C:/__BuildSource/__LIB__/android-ndk-r20-beta2/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\algorithm:644:
In file included from C:/__BuildSource/__LIB__/android-ndk-r20-beta2/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\memory:668:
C:/__BuildSource/__LIB__/android-ndk-r20-beta2/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\atomic:1167:49: error: expected ')'
atomic_is_lock_free(const volatile atomic<_Tp>* __o) _NOEXCEPT
                                                ^
C:/__BuildSource/__LIB__/android-ndk-r20-beta2/build//../sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include\atomic:1167:1: note: to match this '('
atomic_is_lock_free(const volatile atomic<_Tp>* __o) _NOEXCEPT
^
C:/__BuildSource/__LIB__/android-ndk-r20-beta2/build//../toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows\lib\clang\8.0.7\include\stdatomic.h:250:68: note: expanded from macro 'atomic_is_lock_free'
#define atomic_is_lock_free(obj) __c11_atomic_is_lock_free(sizeof(*(obj)))

                                                               ^
```

нашел похожую проблему, но она не содержит ответа https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015275/libbinder-static-compile-error-ndk11c-api-21
NDK последний `android-ndk-r20-beta2`

Код на что ругается:
**cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/atomic**

```
// atomic_is_lock_free

template <class _Tp>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
bool
atomic_is_lock_free(const volatile atomic<_Tp>* __o) _NOEXCEPT
{
    return __o->is_lock_free();
}
```

Где то там еще одноименный макрос определен.. `#define atomic_is_lock_free`

Comment: Ну ясно, что стандартная С функция, реализованная через макро, конфликтует с одноимненной стандартной С++ функцией. Вряд ли это проскользнуло бы незамеченным. Скорее всего у вас случайно перемешались несовместимые реализации С и С++ стандартных библиотек.

Comment: @AnT, Да собственно я как скачал этот релиз, так внутри вообще ничего руками не трогал.. Пока `C` код собирал, проблем не возникало. Пойду предыдущий релиз попробую. Там я еще обратил внимание что в `<memory>` определены одноименные методы.. загадочный дистрибутив.

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround** данного **бага** - правим файл `sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/memory`:

```
#if !defined(_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_ATOMIC_HEADER) /// строка 667
#  include <atomic>                        /// добавляем
//#  include <stdatomic.h>                 /// комментируем
#endif
```

и все начинает собираться.

Для понимания что дело не в коде:

**test.cpp**

```
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { return 0; }
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := teZt
LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp
LOCAL_LDFLAGS := 
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ./
LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := eng
LIBCXX_FORCE_REBUILD := false
LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++17 -Wall
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```